# Why is K-fold cross validation bad for time series?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

If you are about to answer "because k-fold incorporates future information", I'm going to challenge you on that answer :)

If my time series exhibits some pattern (e.g. annual seasonality), that pattern must obviously occur every year, in the past *and* in the future.

For example, if some summer seasonality appears in the 2017 data, it should also appear in 2010, or in 2007, etc. Otherwise it's not really a pattern!

But if seasonality appears every year, then training the Model on chunks of future data and validating the Model on chunks of past data, should be fine as well.

So cross-validation rocks on time series too, right?

Comment: CV works on random splitting of the data, so among (many other things) it's not clear that you would be able to split the data so that seasonality is preserved.

Comment: ok but that would make CV more pessimistic, but that's not too bad. The problem is usually the opposite ... being too optimistic.  

besides K-Fold is no based on splitting the data random, rather in K chunks :)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195414/cross-validation-techniques-for-time-series-data/195438#195438). Let me know if your question should be marked duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @RichardHardy great link!  let's mark it as duplicate, thanks :)

Comment: See https://robjhyndman.com/publications/cv-time-series/