# Does using a random train-test split lead to data leakage?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, validation, data-leakage

I am trying to understand data leakage in modeling practice.

If we had a dataset of patient instances from 2000-2018 (with all patient visits included), and used a randomly selected train-test split (say 80%/20%), would that lead to data leakage?

To me, the answer seems to be **yes**, because a patient could very well have their 2018 visit be included in the 80% train set and their 2011 visit be included in the 20% validation set.

Doesn't this imply that using k-fold cross-validation leads to data leakage? Reason being that the folds internal to the CV process could very well have jumbled up the years.

Edit for clarity: this data is **not** explicitly a time series dataset. It's patient visit data. These visits, viewed closely, have some temporal properties (such as having several visits in different years for the same patient), but it would be inaccurate to say "this is a time series dataset".

Comment: What you write seems correct to me, although "data leakage" is not a term I'm very familiar with. I'd say do your cross-validation so that you can't have the same patient in test and training data.

Comment: That makes sense -- the Wiki for "leakage" is also a little underwhelming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)). I'll keep in mind trying to keep separation between different patients for train and validation sets.

Comment: If you have time dependent data, you must take it into account when sampling. Have a look at h(v)-block CV or walk forward CV for example.

Comment: Looking at what @LaksanNathan said, it seems like the leakage problem is removed if we were to take unique patients (i.e. enforce 1 patient gets 1 visit in the training set). I wonder if doing so would hamper the model's ability to do within-patient stratification, though (distinguish between different visits for the same patient)...

Comment: It really depends on your problem setting.  A random train/test split is appropriate for i.i.d. data.  In your setting, it may make more sense to run your train/test split at the _patient_ level, so that the patients in your test set are by construction never seen in the training set.  But it depends on the goal of your model:  what are you trying to predict?  Do you want a model that performs well on new (never before seen) patients?

Comment: @Adrian here's the tricky part: In production, the model will sometimes see new (never before seen) patients, but it's also the case that many patients experience multiple visits and so the model will **also** see patients that it **has** seen before. Given that goal, it may make sense to make sure that the train & test sets are stratified by (e.g.) year of visit rather than by patient?

Comment: @AmeySMahajan interesting:  in that case, you may want to construct two separate test sets:  one containing never-before-seen users (i.e. users _not_ ever seen in the training set), and another containing later visits from users whose earlier (past) visits _do_ appear in the training set.  You could compute your model accuracy / loss / whatever metrics you are interested on both test groups, and see how you perform in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, random train-test splits can lead to data leakage, and if traditional k-fold and leave-one-out CV are the default procedures being followed, data leakage *will* happen. Leakage is the major reason why traditional CV is not appropriate for time series. Using these cross-validators when you shouldn't will inflate performance metrics since they allow the training model to cheat because observations "from the future" (posterior samples) leak into the training set.

Since time series data is time ordered, we want to keep intact the fact that we must use past observations to predict future observations.  The randomization in the standard cross-validation algorithm does not preserve the time ordering, and we end up making predictions for some samples using a model trained on posterior samples. While this is not immediately a huge problem for some applications, it becomes a critical one if the time series data is often strongly correlated along the time axis. The randomization of traditional CV will make it likely that for each sample in the validation set, numerous strongly correlated samples exist in the train set. This defeats the very purpose of having a validation set: the model essentially “knows” about the validation set already, leading to inflated performance metrics on the validation set in case of overfitting.

One solution is to use **Walk-forward cross-validation** (closest package implementation being [Time Series Split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit) in `sklearn`), which restricts the full sample set differently for each split, but this suffers from the problem that, near the split point, we may have training samples whose evaluation time is posterior to the prediction time of validation samples. Such overlapping samples are unlikely to be independent, leading to information leaking from the train set into the validation set. To deal with this, **purging** can be used.

#### Purging

Purging involves dropping from the train set any sample whose evaluation time is posterior to the earliest prediction time in the validation set. This ensures that predictions on the validation set are free of look-ahead bias. But since walk-forward CV has other grievances, like its lack of focus on the most recent data during training fold construction, the following is becoming more widely adopted for time series data:

#### Combinatorial cross-validation

Consider we abandon the requirement that all the samples in the train set precede the samples in the validation set. This is not as problematic as it may sound. The crucial point is to ensure that the samples in the validation set are reasonably independent from the samples in the training set. If this condition is verified, the validation set performance will still be a good proxy for the performance on new data.

[Combinatorial K-fold cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443159/what-is-combinatorial-purged-cross-validation-for-time-series-data) is similar to K-fold cross-validation, except that we take the validation set to consists in $j < K$ blocks of samples. We then have $K$ choose $j$ possible different splits. This allows us to create easily a large number of splits, just by taking $j = 2$ or $3$, addressing two other problems not mentioned that purging did not address.

It is however clear that we cannot use combinatorial K-fold cross-validation as it stands. We have to make sure that the samples in the train set and in the validation set are independent. We already saw that purging helps reduce their dependence. However, when there are train samples occurring after validation samples, this is not sufficient.

#### Embargoing

We obviously also need to prevent the overlap of train and validation samples at the right end(s) of the validation set. But simply dropping any train sample whose prediction time occurs before the latest evaluation time in the preceding block of validation samples may not be sufficient. There may be correlations between the samples over longer periods of time. In order to deal with such long range correlation, we can define an embargo period after each right end of the validation set. If a train sample prediction time falls into the embargo period, we simply drop the sample from the train set. The required embargo period has to be estimated from the problem and dataset at hand.

A nice feature of combinatorial cross-validation is also that as each block of samples appears the same number of times in the validation set, we can group them (arbitrarily) into validation predictions over the full dataset (keeping in mind that these predictions have been made by models trained on different train sets). This is very useful to extract performance statistics over the whole dataset.

Comment: the only answer I found on SE talking about the so important embargo, congrats!