# Solve unbalanced data set problem in binary classification time series prediction (sampling methods)

Tags: time-series, sampling, svm, predictive-models, unbalanced-classes

I'm using time series data (continuous features) for binary time series prediction (one step ahead, up-turn and down-tern of output of `t+1` comparing to `t` - `t` is time). This is number of samples in every year:

```
            Total    Up     Down
            _____    ___    ____

2009         234     135     99 
2010         243     153     90 
2011         241     132    109 
2012         240     133    107 
2013         240     155     85 
2014         241     110    131 
2015         243     126    117 
2016          29      24      5 
All data    1711     968    743
```

You can see in above table that we are dealing with unbalanced data-set. After I trained `SVM` or `Neural network` models the sensitivity of model is high (70~85%) but the specificity is very low (40~57%). I'm using sliding validation [LINK](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11869/sliding-window-validation-for-time-series). What is your proposed sampling method for improving specificity (down-trend accuracy) in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by unbalanced data set?

Comment: Where is the unbalanced data. I think 968 :743 is not at all unbalanced. Even if you take year on year like 135:99 for 2009, it is not unbalanced data.